# How to get absolute path of compiled deno executable?

Tags: deno

I want to get executable (artifact from `deno compile`) path in script.

I tried `import.meta.url`, `Deno.mainModule` and `Deno.args` but none of them works.

`import.meta.url` didn't changed even if executable location was changed.

`Deno.mainModule` was always `file://$deno$/bundle.js`.

`Deno.args` doesn't contain first parameter(which is executable).

What should I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Deno.execPath()`](https://doc.deno.land/deno/stable/%7E/Deno.execPath) which requires `allow-read` permission.